# Using three.js, how do I determine which plane my mesh is facing?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to build a simple game that shoots stuff out of a barrel of a gun.  So far I have a simple group with a cube and a cylinder added as the barrel.  When I rotate the group (90 degrees at a time) the barrel moves around facing different directions and that all fine.

My problem is that I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to determine which way the barrel of my gun is pointing.  I need to know how to identify the face of the cube that the barrel is attached to and to what part of the 3D world it is facing..either X+, Y+, Z+, X-, Y-, Z-.  Forgive me if my lexicon is all wrong in describing this.  I have not posted any of my attempts because they are not working at all.

Please take a look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/smatthews1999/pen/MyvoJY) for an example of what I'm trying to do...

... and here's some code just because I can't post this on SO w/o it.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    var cylgeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 10, 5, 100, 32 );
        var cylmesh = new THREE.Mesh( cylgeo, material );

        cylmesh.rotateZ(Math.PI/2);
        cylmesh.translateY(35);


var group = new THREE.Group();

group.add( cube );
group.add( cylmesh );

scene.add(group);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, construct your "gun" so the barrel, by default, points up the positive-z axis by modifying your code like so:

```
cylmesh.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );
```

Add a helper axis to your scene so your can see what you are doing:

```
scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 ) );
```

In this configuration, when the parent `group` has rotation zero, the barrel of the gun points up the positive-z axis.

If the parent `group` is rotated, you can get the direction the group (and hence the barrel) is looking like so:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once an reuse
...
group.getWorldDirection( vector );
```

The returned value of `vector` will be unit-length vector pointing in the same direction as the barrel.

three.js r.75

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  If you saw the many horrible lines of code I came up with to try and do this you'd have a good laugh.